# How do I prevent characters from the previous line from appearing when overwriting it in Rust?

Tags: printing, rust, stdout

I have the following code which enables me to make console output appear on the same line. However, if a value that was previously printed was of greater length than values after it, the remnants of the longer value will show up. I have seen other questions about the same thing in languages like Python, but I'm not sure how to overcome this in Rust.

Here's an example:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let fruits = ["Blueberry", "Orange", "Cherry", "Lemon", "Apple"];
    print_value(&fruits);
}

fn print_value(e: &[&str]) {
    for val in e {
        print!("\rStatus: {}", val);
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        // pause program temporarily
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::new(2, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do other languages solve the problem? The naïve solution is to print "a lot" of spaces, and a slightly better solution is to track how long the previous line was and write just that many spaces. Those both seem inelegant. You could also use a library like ncurses that handles some of these details for you.

Comment: Yeah, I did read about adding spaces to solve this in other languages. I'll take a look at ncurses, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some terminals have a special character sequence that, when printed, clears the line to the right of the current cursor position.

VT100-compatible terminals have a character sequence EL0 for that. In Rust it can be expressed with `"\x1B[K"`.

Here's a little [thingy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%2F%2F%2F%20Helper%20printing%20the%20status%20message%20at%20the%20given%20intervals.%0A%23%5Bderive%28Copy%2CClone%29%5D%0Apub%20struct%20ConsoleStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20interval%3A%20f32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20last_update%3A%20f64%2C%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20u32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20slash%3A%20u32%2C%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20ConsoleStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new%28interval%3A%20f32%29%20-%3E%20ConsoleStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ConsoleStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20interval%3A%20interval%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last_update%3A%200.0%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20count%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slash%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Escape%20sequence%20to%20%22Clear%20line%20from%20cursor%20right%22%20%28EL0%29.%20Cf.%20http%3A%2F%2Fascii-table.com%2Fansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20el0%28%29%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5Cx1B%5BK%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Escape%20sequence%20to%20%22Move%20cursor%20up%20n%20lines%22%20%28CUU%29.%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20cuu%28lines%3A%20u8%29%20-%3E%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format!%28%22%5Cx1B%5B%7B%7DA%22%2C%20lines%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Escape%20sequence%20to%20%22Turn%20off%20character%20attributes%22%20%28SGR0%29.%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20sgr0%28%29%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5Cx1B%5Bm%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Escape%20sequence%20to%20%22Turn%20bold%20mode%20on%22%20%28SGR1%29.%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20sgr1%28%29%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5Cx1B%5B1m%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Escape%20sequence%20to%20%22Turn%20low%20intensity%20mode%20on%22%20%28SGR2%29.%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20sgr2%28%29%20-%3E%20%26%27static%20str%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%5Cx1B%5B2m%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20consoleStatus.print%20%28%7Ccount%2Cslash%7C%7Bformat!%20%28%22Indexing%20...%20%7B%7D%7B%7D%22%2C%20count%2C%20slash%29%7D%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Ballow%28deprecated%29%5D%20%20%2F%2F%20for%20flush%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20print%3CR%3E%28%26mut%20self%2C%20renderer%3A%20R%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%20R%3A%20Fn%28u32%2C%20char%29%20-%3E%20String%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.count%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20now%20%3D%20time%3A%3Aprecise_time_s%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28now%20-%20self.last_update%29%20as%20f32%20%3E%20self.interval%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.last_update%20%3D%20now%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.slash%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print!%28%22%5Cr%7B%7D%7B%7D%7B%7D%7B%7D%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ConsoleStatus%3A%3Ael0%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ConsoleStatus%3A%3Asgr2%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20renderer%28self.count%2C%20b%22%7C%2F-%22%5B%28self.slash%20%25%204%29%20as%20usize%5D%20as%20char%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ConsoleStatus%3A%3Asgr0%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20_%20%3D%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3Astdout%28%29.flush%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Like%20%60print%60%20but%20forces%20the%20update%20to%20come%20thru.%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20print_force%3CR%3E%28%26mut%20self%2C%20renderer%3A%20R%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%20R%3A%20Fn%28u32%2C%20char%29%20-%3E%20String%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.last_update%20%3D%200.0%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.print%28renderer%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20consoleStatus.println%20%28%7C_%2C_%7C%22Hello%20world.%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20println%3CR%3E%28%26mut%20self%2C%20renderer%3A%20R%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20where%20R%3A%20Fn%28u32%2C%20char%29%20-%3E%20String%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.print_force%28renderer%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Clear%20the%20current%20line%28s%29%20from%20the%20status%20information%20and%20print%20the%20given%20message%20there.%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Example%3A%20status.log%20%28%22Log%20message.%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20log%28%26mut%20self%2C%20line%3A%20%26str%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%5Cr%7B%7D%7B%7D%22%2C%20ConsoleStatus%3A%3Ael0%28%29%2C%20line%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) that might prove an example.

To do that in a more portable way you use a terminal library, such as [term](https://web.archive.org/web/20181005074642/https://crates.io/crates/term) and it's [delete_line](https://stebalien.github.io/doc/term/term/trait.Terminal.html#tymethod.delete_line) method.